# Invoke another Worklight app page from a Worklight app

Tags: windows-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

All,

I would like to know if it is possible to make interactions among Worklight apps in the same device(phone/tablet). For example, if an enterprise plans to launch a bunch of Worklight apps in their local app store and wanted to show a common page in all the Worklight apps they publish, how we can approach this with making a call to another Worklight app from a worklight app. In detail, i am developing two Worklight apps in both of which i would like to show an HTML page which shows the login for existing users and also "Sign up" option for new users.

--> Login Page(Sing in, Sign up) [with company logo]

1. If "Sing in" clicked - authenticate and show result then go back to previous state of the app
2. If "Sign up" clicked - show "Sign up" HTML page then go back to previous state of the app

I would like to use the above login module functionality in both the apps. Again, I dont want to reuse the code("Sing-in" HTML page, "Sign-up" HTML page, "Results" page) in both the apps but have above set of HTML pages in one of the apps so that I can dynamically invoke them(set of the HTML pages) from another worklight app. Thus, if i want to make any changes in those HTML pages, i will modify and deploy only the app which has those HTML pages.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Please EDIT the question and explain the scenario in greater detail. You have 2 Worklight apps in the same device and you want to show the same page in both, why do you need them to talk with one another for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my question in the comments section above, IMO this is not possible. But you do need to explain what you're looking for in greater detail.

You can just:

- Have the apps get the same data from a backend so they all display the same
- [Integrate server-generated pages](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) in the apps ([sample app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/IntegratingServerGeneratedPagesProject.zip))

Please go over the Getting Started material to familiarize yourself with IBM Worklight.

Comment: I think second approach you mentioned above may work for my scenario. Is there any other solution than this? In Android, i can call the Activity of one app from another app. So was wondering if we can do the same with Worklight apps.

Comment: 1) what is the end-user has app A but not app B? I don't think you can count on this sort of behavior. 2) calling an activity is not the same is calling specific web resources as far as I understand it, an activity is the "app" whereas an HTML is a resources of the app and hopefully is sandboxed so you wouldn't be able to get to it anyway (think security and rogue apps). I think you should try the approach I've suggested.